# Word Wander - Connect the Words

Tags: word, wordplay, word-ladder

A Word Wander, also called a "Synogram", is a word puzzle that requires you to connect the first and last word by following a certain pattern. Each word down the puzzle must be either a synonym of the word above it or a fragment of that word, in an alternating sequence. The words to the right of the puzzle are synonyms of the word adjacent to them. In some of the more difficult puzzles there may be gaps in these hint synonyms. If you get stuck, it can be helpful to work from the bottom up.

Here is an example puzzle connecting the words "Momentous" and "Urge":
[image: Connect the words "Momentous" and "Urge". Solution: Omen, Harbinger, Binge, Splurge]

First we must use a fragment of the word "momentous". We can see in the hints at the bottom that this word is 4 letters long, begins with an O, and ends with an N. We can also see from the right side that "prophecy" is a related word. Next, we must find a synonym of "Omen" that is also a synonym of herald, begins with an H, ends with an R, and is 9 letters long. This pattern repeats until the final word.

Can you solve these 3 puzzles of increasing difficulty?

Puzzle 1:

[image: Connect the words "link" and "uplift"]

Puzzle 2:

[image: Connect the words "guiltless" and "grasp"]

Puzzle 3: (Notice that the first word doesn't have a hint synonym!)
[image: Connect the words "digit" and "imp"]

Comment: Would this be close enough to a [[tag:word-ladder]] to merit the tag? Also - welcome to Puzzling, nice first puzzle! Feel free to join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair) for more informal discussion.

Comment: @bobble Good point, I added the word-ladder tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's all 3:

---

**Puzzle 1:**

> **Link**
> Connection
> Connect
> Relate
> Elate
> **Uplift**

**Puzzle 2:**

> **Guiltless**
> Irreproachable
> Reproach
> Reprehension
> Prehension
> Grasping
> **Grasp**

**Puzzle 3:**

> **Digit**
> Dactyl
> Act
> Routine
> Out
> Impermissible
> **Imp**